# Java Regex to get phrases

Tags: java, regex, arraylist

I have a String list but with a lot of informations in it like dates, prices, numbers and phrases like this:

```
01/01/2018
123 -TESTING. PHRASE (I want to get this phrase)
98765
1.274.89
```

I can get the other information with a for loop and Regex, but I cannot make a Regex to match the phrases inside the list, only the dates the other numbers and prices, I tried somethings like this to match the phrases:

```
^[a-zA-Z]\D+$
[\w[.*]]+
```

I'm starting to learn about Regex, and I'm having a lot of difficulties...

Comment: Check regex group.

Comment: what do you mean with "phrases" ??? which special are allowed on your phrases ??  '.' (point ??) '!' (exclamation) ?? please be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a phrase is defined as a line containing text (as opposition to dates, prices and numbers), the following should be good

[`^.*\[A-Za-z\].*$`](https://regex101.com/r/Gk4adg/1)

It just takes anything with a letter in it, may it be lower or uppercase.